# determining input vs textarea in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I wish to iterate through a form, adding each element to an area. The problem is that some of these elements are select, input, and textboxes. I know that I can use `:input` to solve the problem here (though, I don't really need to). The issue is that I'm having trouble determining how I could see whether or not the element is a textarea, input, select, etc. I need to do this properly because, as far as I know, `jQuery("input#someinput").val()` works great for inputs, but for a textarea I may need `jQuery("textarea#sometexarea").text()`. I'm not sure if this exists...

Anyway, here's my function so far:

```
function getAllFormElements(id) {

    var elements = new Array();

    jQuery(id).children().map(function(){

        for (var index = 0; index < children.length; index++) {

            elements[i] = jQuery(children[i]).val();

        }

    })

        return elements;
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) works equally well with `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements.

If you still want to determine the actual type of elements matched by the `:input` selector, you can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [element selectors](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/):

```
$(":input").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is("input")) {
        // <input> element.
    } else if ($this.is("select")) {
        // <select> element.
    } else if ($this.is("textarea")) {
        // <textarea> element.
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, nice solution `Frédéric`, found it today and worked for me too. @aboutblank: You should mark this answer as accepted as it seems it also solved your issue.

Comment: Funny how `:input` also seletect a texarea

Comment: @DerkArts.even i felt same thing how select and textarea include it

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use jQuery's .is() function - just pass a selector to .is() and it will return true if the element matches the selector. So, to see if you had a textarea, you would just check:

```
if($(this).is("textarea")) { doStuff(); }
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `nodeName` property.

```
jQuery(id).children().map(function(){
    console.log( children[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() );
});
```

You can but don't have to use the `is` method from jQuery (overhead here).

Comment: Using `nodeName` is fine, but beware of the case. Depending on the document type (HTML or XML) the case of the value returned won't be the same (uppercase or as-is, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

`$.val()` works for both inputs and text areas. You only need `$.text()` for things like divs that don't have a "value" per se.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for the `$(children[i]).attr("tagName");` , which returns the tag of the element, either being select, input, or textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for jQuery, you can easily get all the form inputs using `$(:input)` : http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

> Description: Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.
>       The :input selector basically selects all form controls.

`.val()` also works with text areas, but there is a caveat ... see the docs for reference:
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Frederic posted his answer as I was writing this, and his solution of using `is()` certainly proves out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also interested in the type of "input" (input, checkboxes or radio). You need to dig a bit deeper:

```js
function test(){
  $(":input").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is("input")) {
      type=$this.attr('type');
        $(document.body).append(type+" <br />");
    } else if ($this.is("select")) {
        $(document.body).append("select <br />");
    } else if ($this.is("textarea")) {
        $(document.body).append("textarea <br />");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="test()">get types</button><br />
  <input type="text" value="text input"><br />
  <input type="number" value="12345"><br />
  <textarea>text area</textarea><br />
  <select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
  </select><br />
  <input type="checkbox" checked> checkbox<br />
  <input type="radio"> radio button<br />
```